# The width of a double variable

Tags: java

I am trying to write some text to a file using PrintWriter and I do not understand what "7" means in the next example:

> ```
> double d = 12.11211;
> out.format(“%7.3f”, d);
> ```

The source from where I am inspiring says that 7 means:

> The 7.3 before the f denotes the width (7) and precision (3) to output
>   d in.

The problem is that I cannot understand what that width really means. I mean, even though my variable would have more than 7 digits, it is not going to format anything.

Comment: width - the total number of characters in the formatted output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it as the total length of the string produced by the applied format.  
If you take in account that there will be exactly 3 chars after the decimal point and 1 char for the decimal point itself, then it leaves 3 chars for the integer part.  
Because your number has only 2 digits in the integer part the final result will be padded at the left with a white space:

```
double d = 12.11211;
out.format("%7.3f", d);
```

will create:

```
" 12.112"
```

with

```
out.format("%8.3f", d);
```

you get

```
"  12.112"
```

and so on. 
The minimum length of the formatted string is in your case:

```
6 = 2 chars for the integer part + 1 char for the decimal point + 3 chars for the digits after the decimal point
```

so even if you set:

```
out.format("%5.3f", d);
```

this will not truncate the result, it will be:

```
"12.112"
```

Answer (score 3):

For simple text arguments, you can think of the width and precision as a minimum and  maximum number of characters to be output. For floating-point numeric types, the precision changes meaning slightly and controls the number of digits displayed after the decimal point.

watch this example:

```
System.out.printf("String is '%5s'\n", "A");
// String is '    A'
System.out.printf("String is '%.5s'\n", "Happy Birthday!");
// String is 'Happy'
```

for more information look at this [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-java-4th/9781449372477/ch10s05.html)

Answer (score 3):

Your source of inspiration should be [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). It says:

> The width is the minimum number of characters to be written to the
>   output. If the length of the converted value is less than the width
>   then the output will be padded by '  ' ('\u0020') until the total
>   number of characters equals the width. The padding is on the left by
>   default.[...]
>
> For the floating-point conversions 'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', and 'f' the precision is the number of digits after the radix point.

A simple experiment shows it:

```
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 1.3);
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 12.3);
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 12.34);
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 12.345);
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 12.3456);
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 12.34567);
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 12.34567);
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 123.34567);
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 1234.34567);
    System.out.printf("%7.3f%n", 12345.34567);
```

prints:

```
  1,300
 12,300
 12,340
 12,345
 12,346
 12,346
 12,346
123,346
1234,346
12345,346
```

Answer (score 2):

By width, it means the string will always fill the rest of the places if the number of digits/characters of the value is less than the given number.

```
double d = 12.11211;
String.format(“%7.3f”, d);


> 12.112
 ^^^^^^^
 1234567
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0z8vc-4):

> The field width in a formatting operator is a nonnegative integer that
>   specifies the number of digits or characters in the output when
>   formatting input values. For example, in the operator %7.3f, the field
>   width is 7.
>
> By default, the output text is padded with space
>   characters when the field width is greater than the number of
>   characters.

The `7` adds padding () in case the output is smaller than 7 characters. This way the output is always at least 7 characters, with 3 floating decimals.

This documentation gives a very detailed explanation for formatting text in general, most of which is applicable cross-language.